# Openssl "Self-signed certificate in certificate chain" when server sends whole certificate chain with the self-signed certificate to the client

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, self-signed-certificate, ssl-certificate-errors

I am having the following certificate chain:

Self-signed Certificate --> Intermediate --> Client cert, Server cert. I have application for ssl communication and also verify peer setting. I try to test this chain with `openssl s_client` command and I get `Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)`. The server sends the whole chain in the handshake.

I tried to test this with Bundle.pem which contains the self-signed and the intermediate certificates and also with the Self-signed.pem but the result is the same.

```
openssl s_client -msg -connect localhost:1500 -CAfile Self-signed.pem/Bundle.pem -cert Client.crt -key Client.key
```

Then I issued another intermediate certificate and from that one I issued new server certificate

```
openssl s_client -msg -connect localhost:1500 -CAfile Bundle2.pem -cert Client.crt -key Client.key
```

Bundle2.pem contains the second intermediate certificate and the self-signed certificate and this works fine. Also the server now does not send the whole chain of certificates, its how the application is designed.

Can someone explain why this is a issue, why I cannot make successful verification if server and client have the same intermediate certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding `basicConstraints=CA:TRUE` in `openssl.conf` to the imtermediate certificate when issuing